# moment.js compare ISO8601 date only

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following datetime values in ISO8601 format:

```
2014-01-29T10:13:08Z
2014-01-30T10:13:08Z
2014-01-31T10:13:08Z
2014-02-01T10:13:08Z
2014-02-02T10:13:08Z
2014-02-03T10:13:08Z
```

How can I use moment.js in order to compare the current date to the values from the list above but compare just the date (day, month, year)

For example if today is 31.01.2014 will match the third datetime from above list.

Comment: Why use moment.js? `date1.slice(0, 10) <=> date2.slice(0, 10)`

Comment: Whose "today" do you want to compare it to?  The UTC day? The user's day? Some other timezone's day?  "Today" is a relative term.